# Optimize the Clustered Index Scan into Clustered Index Seek

Tags: sql-server-2012

There is scenario, I have table with 40 columns and I have to select all data of a table (including all columns). I have created a clustered index on the table and its including **Clustered Index Scan** while fetching full data set from the table.

I know that without any filter or join key, SQL Server will choose **Clustered Index Scan** instead of **Clustered Index Seek**. But, I want to have optimize execution plan by optimizing *Clustered Index Scan* into *Clustered Index Seek*. Is there any solution to achieve this? Please share.

Below is the screenshot of the execution plan:
[image]

Comment: Why?  It would run like crap.

Answer (score 2):

Something is not quite right in the question / request, because what you are asking for will perform badly. I suspect it comes from mis-understanding what a clustered index is.

The clustered index - which is perhaps better stated as a clustered table - is the table of data, its not separate to the table, it *is* the table. If the order of the data on the table is already based on ITEM ID then the scan is the most efficient access method for your query (especially given the `select *`) - you do not want to seek in this scenario at all - and I don't believe that it is your scenario due to the sort operator.

If the clustered table is ordered based on another field, then you would need an additional non-clustered index to provide the correct order. You would then try to force a plan which was a non-clustered index scan, nested loop to a clustered index seek. That can be achieved using query hints, most likely an `INNER LOOP JOIN` would cause the seek - but a `FORCESEEK` also exists which can be used.

Performance wise this second option is never going to win - you are in effect looking at a tipping point notion (https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-tipping-point-query-answers/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was trying to achieve the same, I wanted an index seek instead of an index scan on my top query.

```
SELECT TOP 5 id FROM mytable
```

Here is the execution plan being shown for the query:
[image: Query Plan]

I even tried the `Offset Fetch Next` approach, the plan was same.

To avoid a index scan, I included a fake primary key filter like below:

```
SELECT TOP 5 id FROM mytable where id != 0
```

I know, I won't have a 0 value in my primary key, so I added it in top query, which was resolved to an index seek instead of index scan:
[image: Query Plan 2]

Even though, the query plan comparison gives operation cost as similar to other, for index seek and scan in this regard. But I think to achieve index seek this way, it is an extra operation for the `db` to perform because it has to compare whether the id is 0 or not. Which we entirely do not need it to do if we want the top few records.

[image: Query Comparison]